# how do i parse <script type="text/javascript"> python beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.location = 'content_that_I_want_to_parse';
</script>
```

it is simple but I couldn't find something like this as most of questions were made for json

could someone guide me how to parse this?

```
page = s.get('http://theaddress.com')
soup=bs(page.text,'html.parser')
result = soup.find('script'}.get('value')
```

the result i want is as below

```
content_that_I_want_to_parse
```

Comment: `document.location = (some_regex)` might work better if that's all you're interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, tested: `print(soup.script.text)`

Comment: the result is 

'document.location = content_that_I_want_to_parse'

how do i get 'content_that_I_want_to_parse' only?